# JQuery plugin to shard domain names for <img>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, jquery-plugins

I was reading Stoyan Stefanov's [excellent article about JS domain sharding](http://www.phpied.com/simple-sharding-logic/) for image files and wanted to improve his recipe.

The below script will iterate through the images in a page, assign each to a bucket based on the length of the "src" value, and assign it to a bucket (logging this to the console).

What I'm trying to do is create a JQuery plugin that can accept a collection like $('img') or $('link') and rewrite the "src" attribute with a sharded domain like "http://images1.mydomain.com/path/to/image.png".

If my page has:

```
<img src="/Images/file1.png" />
<img src="/Images/filenumber2.png" />
<img src="/Images/footer.png" />
```

I want to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').domainShard(3, "subdomain", "mydomain.com")
});
```

To roughly produce:

```
<img src="http://subdomain1.mydomain.com/Images/file1.png" />
<img src="http://subdomain2.mydomain.com/Images/filenumber2.png" />
<img src="http://subdomain3.mydomain.com/Images/footer.png" />
```

Using a JQuery plugin like so:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.domainShard = function (buckets, subdomain, domain) {
        var numBuckets =  buckets || 3;
        var subdomain = subdomain || "images";
        var domain = domain || "mydomain.com";
        return this.each(function () {
            // look at the src
                // var src = $(this).attr('src');
            // compute bucket assignment
                // do stuff
            // set the new path
                // newSrc = $(this).attr('src', path);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is Stoyan's Javascript:

```
function getBucket(url, numbuckets) {
  var number = url.length,
  group = number % numbuckets;
  return group;
}

function toBuckets(stuff, numbuckets) {
  var numbuckets = parseInt(numbuckets, 10),
  url, group,
  buckets = Array(numbuckets),
  cache = {};
    for (var i = 0, max = stuff.length; i < max; i++) {
        url = stuff[i].src;

        if (typeof cache[url] === 'number') {
            continue;
        }
        group = getBucket(url, numbuckets);
        if (!buckets[group]) {
            buckets[group] = [];
        }
        buckets[group].push(url);
        cache[url] = group;
    }
    return buckets;
}

console.log(toBuckets(document.images, 3));
```

I'll keep hacking away and report back when I have something working -- any advice or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Update: we'll probably do this on the server side with something like mod_pagespeed for Apache, but for IIS (whatever that is).

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/domains#shard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("img").domainShared("striano.net", "images", true);
        });

        $.fn.domainShared = function (topDomain, subDomain, useSSL) {
            return this.each(function () {
                var _this = $(this)
                if (useSSL) {
                    _this.attr("src", "https://" + subDomain + "." + topDomain + _this.attr("src"));
                } else {
                    _this.attr("src", "http://" + subDomain + "." + topDomain + _this.attr("src"));
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Great, I forgot about SSL! In order to assign "subdomain1.striano.net, subdomain2, subdomain3.. etc." I think we need to add a method that looks at the `src` attribute and returns an integer.  Basically what the getBucket(url, numbuckets){} function is doing above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using protocol-relative:

```
_this.attr("src", "//" + subDomain + "." + topDomain + _this.attr("src"));
```